# How to pass callback function in Link "to" attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using React 16.6 and react-router v4 for a master-detail web application. I'm showing headers in a navbar, with individual elements rendered using React Router and Links. Using  components I can easily render array elements, but I want to allow in-place editing for each component with state changes propagated back to the parent.

Following details [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object), I've tried passing a callback function using state in the "to" object. The function isn't available when I inspect the component constructor.

Example

```
<Link class="col" to={{pathname: `/listing/${id}`,  state: {entity: elem, callback: updateComponent}}}>{elem['name']}</Link>
```

Where updateComponent is a function.

What's the preferred way to approach this scenario?

Comment: So listing is your component where you are showing the details of that ID and from the same component you want to allow editing and changes has to update in parent component, am I right ?

Comment: That’s correct!

Answer (score 0):

Just glanced it over and from what I gather the `action` is for the History.

`action - (string) The current action (PUSH, REPLACE, or POP)`

You could trigger callbacks with `onClick`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I’d like for the child component to choose when to update based on user interaction. My understanding (and I could be wrong) is that onClick would only apply on initial render.

Comment: The child component could have a prop passed like doRender={this.state.renderChild} ... your click could trigger this.dosomething = () => { // which could change up your this.state.doRender } and then your child component could use the componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) lifecycle to evaluate the new props and call it's own functions to do things with it.